# Fastest way to cast values to their respective datatypes in Python

Tags: python, performance, casting

I have a list of values - all strings. I want to convert these values to their respective datatypes. I have mapping of values to the types information available.

There are three different datatypes: int, str, datetime.
The code needs to be able to handle the error cases with the data.

I am doing something like:-

```
tlist =  [ 'some datetime value', '12', 'string', .... ]

#convert it to: [ datetime object, 12, 'string', ....]

error_data = ['', ' ', '?', ...]

d = { 0: lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,...) if x not in error_data else x, 
      1: lambda x: int(x) if x not in error_data else 0,
      2: lambda x: x 
      ...
     }

result = [ d[i](j) for i, j in enumerate(tlist) ]
```

The list to convert is very long, like 180 values and I need to do it for thousands of such lists. The performance of above code is very poor. What is the fastest way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the mapping of types you want? i.e. Do you always know that `tlist[0]` should be a `datetime`, etc?

Comment: yeah I know the mapping of types.

Comment: Is it a database you take the values from?

Comment: I am reading these values from simpledb, which stores these values in a plain CSV format. So when I read values, I get CSV values. I convert these CSV values into individual lists and then the task is to convert it to something I mentioned above.

Comment: how long is `error_data`?  If it's long, converting it to a `set` would speed things up.

Comment: error data is not that long it is like 6 values.

Comment: Something is not right.  Converting thousands of 180 item lists should not take very long.  Is your code I/O bound?  Does it still take a long time if you `pass` rather than doing any conversions?  In other words, how long does it take to pull the data?

Comment: for 2 hours of data - which is like 3,60,000 lines(lists), if I pass, it takes 1 min 19 sec. If I try to cast, it takes 7.5 minutes.

Comment: Do you really mean that for each long list having around 180 items, the dictionary ``d`` is known and have the same number of items ? Are all the dictionaries the same one, that is to say every key n has the same function value associated whatever, the list which is considered ?

Comment: Know the list is 180 items long

Comment: Where does each dictionary associated with a list come from ? If there are only three types and around 180 items in each list, that means that the associated dictionary has several times the same function as values for several keys.

Comment: Perhaps you could paste a more complete example at https://gist.github.com/ and put a link to it in your question.

Comment: What is true ? I asked several question and you give only one incomprehensible answer. Do you realize that we don't know your problem as thoroughly than you ? If you don't want to make effort to give information, you won't have a lot of help.

Comment: If error values are rare you would be better off turning your lambdas in to functions and using try/catch so you don't need to do a lookup to search for error values on each conversion.

Comment: @eyquem - I am sorry, I thought we are in sync here. nways - I know the mapping of list values to their types. So I build the dictionary(d), as I mentioned in the question. Yes, the dictionary has same functions over and over again.

Comment: As it is hard to use comments to communicate, I put my words in my answer. So, please, read my answer and edits I will do (if I do..) (If sync==synchronisation: no, the sync isn't automatic on SO )

Comment: You can use an "extra large" Amazon EC2 instance for $0.68/hour. Once you've optimized your code as much as you can just put it up there and it flies. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all those approaches. Yeah, I tried pretty much all the approaches mentioned, but none did perform well.

I tried the following approach and it worked pretty well for my performance needs. This is what I did.

1. I handled the datetime values as suggested by utdemir
2. I've inserted value 0 for all the int error values with code like -

   `[i] = value if value != '' else 0`
3. Instead of coercing value by value using dictionary, I coerced all the value at once using a list.

   `def coerce(l):

   return [ l[0], int(l[1]), int(l[2]) ... ]`

My Observations:

1. handling the error cases separately and coercing at once helps a lot.
2. letting the code recover from an exception takes a lot of time.
3. Going over a list multiple times doesn't really hurt( I did it for handling error cases)
4. To give an idea, for couple of hours of data (0.60 million records), my approach brought down the runtime from 6-7 minutes to 2m30s

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
>>> values = ["12", "a", "bcd", "2.2"]
>>> types = [int, int, str, float]
>>> defaults = {int: 0, float: 0.0}
>>> res = []
>>> for v, f in itertools.izip(values, types): #Just use zip for Python 3+.
    try:
        res.append(f(v))
    except ValueError:
        res.append(defaults[f])
>>> print(res)
[12, 0, 'bcd', 2.2]
```

**Edit:**

This doesn't handle datetime values. My solution for that is use `str` for that, and convert to datetime after the loop, like:

```
res[0] = datetime.strptime(res[0], "...")
```

Both getting and setting the list item has O(1) complexity, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I like the use of try/except.  Since the question is asking for optimizations I would use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`.

Comment: How does this handle datetime conversions?

Comment: this looks like the right approach, I will try right away and let you guys know. Thank you.

Comment: @utdemir Defining another problem (out are the datetime strings) makes it easy to solve.

Comment: apparently recovering from the exception takes a lot of performance hit. I am still testing my code - still after implementing the code as you suggested, it takes more time to run. I will keep everyone posted about my findings.

Comment: Handling dates, like any of the other types, is easy. Just put `lambda v: datetime.strptime(v, '%Y-%m-%d')` in the `types` list. With the right datetime format obviously. To support default values for the values you can just declare the datetime "converter" before and use it as a key in `defaults`.

Answer (score 2):

If your datetime value is always consistant why not let the type casting handle the invalid data that you're trying to manage in error_data. This is not as sexy as some solutions but makes managing type conversion based on position of data in list a little easier to maintain and expand upon.

```
def convert(position, val):
    if position == 0:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # assuming date is in a constant format
        except ValueError:
            return val
    elif position in (1, 15, 16): # assuming that you have other int values in other "columns"
        try:
            return int(val)
        except ValueError:
            return 0
    else: # string type
       return val

result = [convert(i,j) for i, j in enumerate(tlist)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the types you want to convert to, you probably won't get a performance boost from trying to optimize your conversions. The poor performance probably comes from repeatedly iterating over `error_data`. If it is possible, reconstruct your `error_data` list as a `set` to exploit nature of that type:

```
error_set = set((err, None) for err in error_data)
```

Then proceed as you have been. Further improvements would require profiling your code to actually determine where time is being spent.

Comment: I saw your comment right after I posted my answer, and updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There's an incongruity in your code:

if all elements in a list are strings, you can't write `datetime(x)` with **x** being a string

#### edit

It depicts nothing since it is incongruous. The complexity of what is not in you code doesn't justify the weirdness that is in your code. As long as you won't explain how you can pass a string as argument to the function **datetime.datetime()**, nobody will be able to help you, IMO.

### Edit

I think that it's better to create directly your list at the moment the file is read.

I wrote an example:

.

First, I created a CSV file with the following code:

```
import csv
from random import randint,choice
from time import gmtime


xx = ['Whose', 'all', 'birth', 'just', 'infant', 'William',
      'dearest', 'rooms', 'find', 'Deserts', 'saucy', 'His',
      'how', 'considerate', 'only', 'other', 'Houses', 'has',
      'Fanny', 'them', 'his', 'very', 'dispense', 'early',
      'words', 'not', 'thus', 'now', 'pettish', 'Worth']

def gen(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield ['AAAA','%d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d' % gmtime(randint(0,80000000))[0:6],'@@@']
        yield ['BBBB',randint(100,999),'^^^^^^']
        yield ['CCCC',choice(xx),'-----------------']

with open('zzz.txt','wb') as f:
    writ = csv.writer(f, delimiter='#')
    writ.writerows(x for x in gen(60))
```

The structure of the CSV file is so:

```
AAAA#1972/02/11 08:53:53#@@@
BBBB#557#^^^^^^
CCCC#dearest#-----------------
AAAA#1971/10/15 06:55:20#@@@
BBBB#668#^^^^^^
CCCC#?#-----------------
AAAA#1972/07/13 11:10:05#@@@
BBBB#190#^^^^^^
CCCC#infant#-----------------
AAAA#1971/11/22 19:31:42#@@@
BBBB#202#^^^^^^
CCCC##-----------------
AAAA#1971/06/12 05:48:39#@@@
BBBB#81#^^^^^^
CCCC#find#-----------------
AAAA#1970/12/09 06:26:29#@@@
BBBB#72#^^^^^^
CCCC#find#-----------------
AAAA#1972/07/05 10:45:32#@@@
BBBB#270#^^^^^^
CCCC#rooms#-----------------
AAAA#1972/06/23 05:52:20#@@@
BBBB#202#^^^^^^
CCCC##-----------------
AAAA#1972/03/21 23:06:47#@@@
BBBB#883#^^^^^^
CCCC#William#-----------------
...... etc
```

.

The following code extracts the data in a similar way to what you want.

There is no need of a dictionary, a tuple is sufficient. Given the structure of the CSV file created, I defined  `funcs = 60 * (to_dt, int, lambda x: x)` but you'll use the succession of functions that is your dictionary's values (sorted)

```
import re
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import izip

reg = re.compile('(\d{4})/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)')

def to_dt(x, error_data = ('', ' ', '?')):
    if x in error_data:
        return x
    else:
        return datetime(*map(int,reg.match(x).groups()))

def teger(x,  error_data = ('', ' ', '?')):
    if x in error_data:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(x)

funcs = 60 * (to_dt, int, lambda y: y)

with open('zzz.txt','rb') as f:
    rid = csv.reader(f, delimiter='#')
    li = [fct(x[1]) for fct,x in izip(funcs,rid)]



# display
it = (str(el) for el in li).next
print '\n'.join('%-21s %4s  %10s' % (it(),it(),it()) for i in xrange(60))
```

result

```
1972-02-11 08:53:53    557     dearest
1971-10-15 06:55:20    668           ?
1972-07-13 11:10:05    190      infant
1971-11-22 19:31:42    202            
1971-06-12 05:48:39     81        find
1970-12-09 06:26:29     72        find
1972-07-05 10:45:32    270       rooms
1972-06-23 05:52:20    202            
1972-03-21 23:06:47    883     William
1970-02-08 23:47:26    617            
1970-10-08 09:09:33    387     William
1971-04-30 11:05:07    721           ?
1970-02-12 11:57:48    827     Deserts
1972-03-27 21:30:39    363        just
1971-06-02 00:23:52    977            
1970-04-20 04:38:38    113     William
1971-01-20 23:10:26     75       Whose
1971-07-01 12:46:13    352     dearest
1971-01-31 17:01:34    220     William
1970-06-09 20:38:52    148       rooms
1971-08-08 07:42:10    146            
1970-01-28 15:17:41    903        find
...............etc
```

Comment: OK .. the problem here is how to convert all those values to their respective types ... the actual code is part of a very complex data-collection framework so I couldn't copy/paste it. I just wanted to write the relevant portion of the code, which depicts the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be much faster, but to me it's clearer:

```
tlist =  [ 'some datetime value', '12', 'string', .... ]

#convert it to: [ datetime object, 12, 'string', ....]

error_data = set(['', ' ', '?', ...])

def s(x):
    return x

def d(x):
    return datetime(x) if x not in error_data else x

def i(x):
    return int(x) if x not in error_data else 0

types = [ d, i, s, s, s, i, i, d, i, ... ]

result = [ t(x) for t, x in zip(types, tlist) ]
```

As others have mentioned, I'm using a set for the error values, which will be faster than the list you had.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant on utdemir's answer, if error values are fairly infrequent, then you could optimize the common case:

```
>>> values = ["12", "a", "bcd", "2.2"]
>>> types = [int, int, str, float]
>>> defaults = {int: 0, float: 0.0}
>>> try: res = [f(v) for v,f in zip(values,types)]
... except: 
...     res = []
...     for v, f in zip(values, types):
...        try:
...             res.append(f(v))
...         except ValueError:
...             res.append(defaults[f])
```

I.e., first try converting the whole line assuming that nothing will go wrong.  If anything does go wrong, then go back and convert values one at a time, fixing any error values.